# Sound interaction between two sprites in MIT Scratch

Tags: audio, mit-scratch

I am trying to create a DJing program in which one song starts when a sprite is clicked and another song starts (and the first one stops) when a second sprite is clicked. My solution has been to create a variable and use it as an on/off boolean, however the first song continues when the second song is activated. The code for the other sprite is the same with the variables changed.[image]

Comment: Is this song the only audio you have running? You could do `when this sprite clicked: [stop all sounds] [start sound for this sprite]` for both sprites. As far as I know, `stop this script` isn't going to stop the sound triggered by the script but it looks like you can use [`set volume to 0%` per sprite or clone](https://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/topic/97954/?page=1#post-847718). See also [1](https://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/topic/245081/?page=1#post-2508809) [2](https://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/m/topic/245143/)

Answer (score 1):

I misstated the question: I'd actually like to keep one song playing (even if the other song is activated) until the related sprite (button) is clicked again. But using the suggestion of 'set volume to 0%' I was able to create this solution: [image]

Answer (score 0):

In fact you need no boolean. For first sprite the code is

When sprite clicked

stop all sounds

start sound (*whatever sound you have*)

For other sprite you do the same thing